# FirebaseInstanceIdService clarification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the process of converting my GCM app to FCM I have now implemented MyFirebaseInstanceIDService as per [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).  I understand that this replaces the GCM process of GoogleCloudMessaging.Register.

What I don’t understand is . . .

When I originally signed up to use GCM I was given a 12 digit numeric “Google cloud messging key” that was known as SENDER_ID.  When my app registered with GCM it had to supply this SENDER_ID in order to receive back the GCM Registration ID.  That seemed to make sense because this identified me when registering.  I only needed this key once and used it for all of the GCM apps that I wrote.

I no longer have to provide a SENDER_ID  and, I guess, this means I no longer need my “Google cloud messaging key.”  Is this correct?

Has the SENDER_ID been replaced by the registration process of each of my apps with the firebase console?  If this is correct this means I have to identify each of my apps to FCM where I only had to identify myself once to GCM.  Is this correct?

Comment: The Sender ID is included in the google-services.json file you download and put in your project, which I believe is used by FCM for the registration process. The google-services.json file also includes the some details for the apps that you associated in your Firebase Project via the console. So you must add them before downloading the google-services file and putting them in your app projects.

Comment: It looks like that is the "project_number".  ok. Thanks again.